# Spacing (Spoofed Keyboard) Buttons Evenly Across Android LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have an XML layout which I'm attempting to add a series of buttons to (A-Z). Thus far I have been able to do so - however they appear lumped together on the left hand side. I'd like for them to be evenly spaced - and I thought that using something such as:

```
 android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
 android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
```

Would space them evenly across the screen - however I'm left with multiple errors stating:

```
 "Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_marginLeft' with value 'fill_parent')."
```

ScreenShot: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVfAf.png

Current Source:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="00dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- 1st Child Layout  (Nested In Parent Layout) with Horizontal Orientation -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/searchbar"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbartxtcontainer"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="  Search Movies" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:entries="@array/home_spinner1_array"
             android:prompt="@string/select_location" 
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbartxtcontainer"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
            android:hint="Rating" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:entries="@array/home_spinner2_array"
             android:text="Genre"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
            android:hint="Genre" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner1"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbartxtcontainer" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:background="#4D4D4D"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="Reset" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="Sort by:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"  />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbartxtcontainer"
            android:hint="Release Date" 
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- 2nd Child Layout  (Nested In Parent Layout) with Horizontal Orientation -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttona"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="B" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonc"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttond"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="D" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttone"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="E" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonf"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="F" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttong"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="G" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonh"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="H" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoni"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="I" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonj"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="J" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonk"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="K" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonl"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="L" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonm"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="M" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="N" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttono"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="O" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonp"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="P" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonq"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="Q" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonr"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="R" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="S" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttont"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="T" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonu"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="U" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonv"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="V" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonw"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="W" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonx"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="X" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttony"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="Y" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonz"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="Z" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >

        <!-- 3rd Child Layout  (Nested In Parent Layout) with Horizontal Orientation -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- Container view to scroll horizontally which gives the carousel effect -->

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <!-- Carousel items container - lays out items horizontally -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/carousel1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <!-- Container view to scroll horizontally which gives the carousel effect -->

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <!-- Carousel items container - lays out items horizontally -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/carousel2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <!-- Container view to scroll horizontally which gives the carousel effect -->

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <!-- Carousel items container - lays out items horizontally -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/carousel3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <!-- Container view to scroll horizontally which gives the carousel effect -->

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <!-- Carousel items container - lays out items horizontally -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/carousel4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <!-- Container view to scroll horizontally which gives the carousel effect -->

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <!-- Carousel items container - lays out items horizontally -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/carousel5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <!-- Carousel items container - lays out items horizontally -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/carousel6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <!-- Carousel items container - lays out items horizontally -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/carousel7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <!-- 4th Child Layout  (Nested In Parent Layout) with Horizontal Orientation -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</ProgressBar>
<!-- List of Actions (pages) -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_item_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_marginLeft' with value 'fill_parent').  states that you should not give string values for this attribute. You have to give integer values in pixel/dp/dip

ie) layout_marginLeft="10px"

Comment: I understand that - I simply want them to be spaced depending upon how much room is available (so they appear correctly spaced on different screen sizes)

Answer (score 0):

I see you have the buttons in a LinearLayout. You can use android:layout_weight set on the children(Buttons) in this case. The trick is to not use android:weightSum on the LinearLayout with a variable number of buttons.
The below example will stretch the buttons along the LinearLayout. If you want the button size to remain fixed then wrap each Button in another LinearLayout (which will hold the layout_weight property).

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text_1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text_2"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text_3"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text_4"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```